# What is the meaning of a typedef declaration with [100] at the end?

Tags: c++, typedef

What does the following mean in C++?

```
typedef PComplex RComplex [100];
```

Note, PComplex is a user-defined type in my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RComplex is a synonym for `PComplex[100]`. Typedefs have a similar syntax to variable declarations, except in place of a variable name you get a typename.

Comment: I would use the term "Type Alias" rather than synonym. But essentially correct.

Answer (score 2):

This aliases RComplex to the type "array (of length 100) of PComplex", also known as `PComplex[100]`.  The following two variable declarations give each the same type: (after the above typedef)

```
PComplex a[100];
RComplex b;
```

Answer (score -1):

The declares a type synonym called PComplex which is actually an array of 100 RComplex items.